# Store Image In Other Server Path Using Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, file-io

```
public void storeEmployeeImageDetails(String folderPath, List<Employee> listEmp) {
        try {
            for (Employee emp : listEmp) {
                Blob image;
                String imageType;
                image = emp.getImageBlob();
                imageType = emp.getImageType();
                String empId = emp.getEmployeeID();

                if (!"".equals(imageType) && image != null) {
                    String type = imageType.substring(1);
                    int blobLength = (int) image.length();
                    byte[] blobAsBytes = image.getBytes(1, blobLength);
                    BufferedImage imageData = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(blobAsBytes));
                    ImageIO.write(imageData, type, new File(folderPath + empId + imageType));
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Exception Occured While Storing Employee Image In Server Folder: " + e);
        }

    }
```

**I'm Getting Error:**
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https:\example.com\hr\uploads\profilepics\100.jpg (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

*NB:* Here **folderPath** is
`https:\\example.com\\hr\\uploads\\profilepics\\` I'm getting from application.properties file.

`https:\\example.com` is a godaddy server, And It's a PHP project. I'm trying to store images from java application to that server.

Comment: From the little explanation you provided it looks like you want to store a file somewhere in the file system on another server. That should not be possible using http since if it were it would be a security hole. So even if you'd be able to manage that you shouldn't rely on it. Have a look at the API of that server and what it provides (it might accept some path as a query/post parameter).

Comment: that URL is not a rest API. It's a folder in their server. with write permission.

Comment: It's not about permissions, it's about networking.

Comment: Well this doesn't have anything to do with REST. If you want to use HTTP the server needs to provide an endpoint/http handler which might be able to translate arbitrary urls into local paths. However, ImageIO won't be able to do this - you need to use a url connection (ideally use a HttpClient e.g. as provided by Apache Commons Http) and post the image to that url.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FTPUploader {
    
    FTPClient ftp = null;
    public FTPUploader(String host, String user, String pwd) throws Exception{
        ftp = new FTPClient();
        ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
        int reply;
        ftp.connect(host);
        reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
            ftp.disconnect();
            throw new Exception("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
        }
        ftp.login(user, pwd);
        ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    }
    
    
    public void uploadFile(byte[] localFileFullName, String fileName, String hostDir)
            throws Exception {
        
        try {
            InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(localFileFullName);
            this.ftp.storeFile(hostDir + fileName, input);
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

    public void disconnect(){
        if (this.ftp.isConnected()) {
            try {
                this.ftp.logout();
                this.ftp.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException f) {
                // do nothing as file is already saved to server
            }
        }
    }
}
```